# How to find out, what URLs Composer will need to access for loading packages?

Tags: dependencies, composer-php

I'm working behind a corporate proxy, that only permit connections to a defined list of URLs. So I need to communicate to the admin, what URLs I need for my application. Well, in either case access to `https://getcomposer.org` and `https://packagist.org` is needed. And most likely also to `https://github.com`. But the packages (dependencies and their dependencies, and the dependencies of their dependencies etc.) might need further connections.

**How to find out, what connections will be needed for a given application (or better: for a given `composer.json`)?**

Answer (score 7):

With the latest version of `composer`

```
$ composer --version

Composer version 1.5.1 2017-08-09 16:07:22
```

and assuming you have run

```
$ composer clear-cache
```

to clear the local cache (otherwise composer will install from the local cache and not download from anywhere) and you have run

```
$ rm -rf vendor
```

to clear the `vendor` directory (as otherwise there's no need to install anything), and also assuming dependencies are installed from `dist`, run

```
$ composer install -vvv 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=Downloading )http(s)?.*'
```

Depending on whether `composer.lock` exists, this will produce different results, though:

#### `composer.lock` exists

`composer` has the information about where to fetch what dependency from, so it will only download from the GitHub API in this case.

```
https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/filesystem/zipball/b32a0e5f928d0fa3d1dd03c78d020777e50c10cb
https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/event-dispatcher/zipball/54ca9520a00386f83bca145819ad3b619aaa2485
https://api.github.com/repos/php-fig/log/zipball/4ebe3a8bf773a19edfe0a84b6585ba3d401b724d
https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/debug/zipball/084d804fe35808eb2ef596ec83d85d9768aa6c9d
...
```

#### `composer.lock` does not exist

`composer` will download meta data from `packagist.org` first:

```
https://packagist.org/packages.json
http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013%2456386a41dbd41eab668ffb05897f08b3d6976a85f637cecc2b4355a8c747f315.json
http://packagist.org/p/provider-2014%2483b2e5e0311688cd390926bf3970c838fe101b3fdd40a9c8c1717a367b3c87a5.json
http://packagist.org/p/provider-2015%24318fb1f4ae87f2f15840c4dd9113d965a3c6da36a45ba1278caacdf0e4471ea7.json
...
```

followed by downloading data from the GitHub API

```
https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/filesystem/zipball/b32a0e5f928d0fa3d1dd03c78d020777e50c10cb
https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/event-dispatcher/zipball/54ca9520a00386f83bca145819ad3b619aaa2485
https://api.github.com/repos/php-fig/log/zipball/4ebe3a8bf773a19edfe0a84b6585ba3d401b724d
https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/debug/zipball/084d804fe35808eb2ef596ec83d85d9768aa6c9d
...
```

**Note**

Redirecting the output from `STDERR` to `STDOUT` as `composer` outputs the relevant information in *verbose* mode to `STDERR` with

```
$ composer install -vvv 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=Downloading )http(s)?.*'
```

and then piping that output into `grep`, using a *positive lookbehind* to match everything that matches `http(s)?.*` preceded by `Downloading`.

Answer (score 0):

Composer uses only Github to download all dependencies, so allowing only github.com will do fine for any composer.json file. But if you are using any private repository then url for that repo should also be considered.

Comment: So I don't need to add the `getcomposer.org` and `packagist.org` to the white list?

Comment: You do need to whitelist `https://packagist.org/packages.json` as well, as `composer` will attempt to download files from there, too.